# ROS Industrial Moveit is stuck indefinitely

Tags: ros, moveit, abb, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've set up ABB RobotStudio according to the ROS wiki  [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/abb/Tutorials). I'm currently using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.4 with RobotStudio 6.03. The virtual controller log says that the Linux PC is connected. When I run

```
roslaunch abb_irb2400_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch robot_ip:=10.140.60.190
```

the program runs, and I'm able to see Rviz. On trying basic motion planning, the planning happens successfully, but on executing, my Linux terminal is stuck on this:

```
[ INFO] [1464764643.403390805]:Received new trajectory execution service request...
```

At the same time, the virtual controller log displays:

```
ROS_MotionServer -> Sending 20 points to MOTION task
```

The robot in RobotStudio doesn't move at all. The initial positions for Rviz as well as RobotStudio are the same. Any idea what's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235762/ros-industrial-moveit-is-stuck-indefinitely/) by [karthikj219](https://answers.ros.org/users/27014/karthikj219/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-01**:
Things to check: robot is in auto mode?

**Comment by [karthikj219](https://answers.ros.org/users/27014/karthikj219/) on 2016-06-01**:
It was in manual, I solved it though. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it on my own. Turns out that making `execution_planning_duration=false` means you have to remove the `allowed_execution_duration_scaling` and the `allowed_goal_duration_margin`. I had to do this because I was initially getting the error

```
Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory
```

So, replacing the goal duration and execution duration scaling parameters did the trick.

---

Originally posted by [karthikj219](https://answers.ros.org/users/27014/karthikj219/) with karma: 11 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-01**:
You shouldn't have to 'remove' those parameters if you correctly disabled the execution monitoring. Did you follow the procedure documented in [How do I disable execution_duration_monitoring ?](http://answers.ros.org/question/196586) After disabling, the other parameters should be ignored.

**Comment by [karthikj219](https://answers.ros.org/users/27014/karthikj219/) on 2016-06-01**:
I used the link you've mentioned above to disable duration monitoring. It didn't directly work, until I commented out the other 2 parameters. Is this a possible bug?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-01**:
You set the parameter to `false` in the sub namespace? It's always worked for me that way, so I'd be surprised if this is no longer the case.